# Calling admob only once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

im having issues with admob for unity, I got the ads working and displaying after a player dies in the game, however if you die very quickly many times in a row the game crashes and I suspect it has to do with requesting ads to fast.

Requesting the ads:

```
private const string AD_UNIT_ID = "hidden_for_privacy";
private AdMobPlugin admob;

void Start () {


    admob = GetComponent<AdMobPlugin> ();
    admob.CreateBanner (AD_UNIT_ID, AdMobPlugin.AdSize.SMART_BANNER, true);
    admob.RequestAd ();
    admob.HideBanner ();

    print ("loaded");
}
```

If you die, ads are shown via

```
    public void showAds(){   print ("showing ads");  admob.ShowBanner();  }
```

and a gui comes up, when you click the button the level reloads and so does the entire script and start function and thus another request gets made.

```
void OnGUI() {
    if (show) {
                    GUI.Box (new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), "");


                        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100, 150, 600, 300), "Play again")){
                            Application.LoadLevel("level1");
                            show = false;
                            hideAds();                                                                                 }                    
}
```

Problem being that everytime the player dies this start function gets called over and over (and as i stated earlier the games slows down and crashes if this is done to rapidly), surely I should somehow be able to only request the ad once per "session" and then just hide/show the ads as i please during that session. It seems heavy to request ads so frequently.

Regards,
Emil

Answer (score 1):

Take full control of your ads. Please don't request on every start. To do that you can use DontDestroyOnLoad(). It will not be destroyed and start again when your scene changes. Also check for any duplicates. Long story short-

```
private static bool created = false;
.....
void Start () {
    admob = GetComponent<AdMobPlugin> ();
    admob.CreateBanner (AD_UNIT_ID, AdMobPlugin.AdSize.SMART_BANNER, true);
    admob.RequestAd ();
    admob.HideBanner ();
    print ("loaded");
}

void Awake(){
    if(!created){
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        created = true;
    } else {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Use a timer function (your session), so that after a basic period of time, if the player die, you show the ads by your code. And don't request the ads if the player die earlier. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but a problem persists, if i destroy the object created it gives a reference error, and if i do not destroy it it will create a copy and thus the problem percists, but you put me on the right track here.

Comment: private static bool created = false; I forgot to mention in my codes. Declare the bool created as static. Hope it will  solve the duplicate problem. Updated the answer.